# Change elements id only for the newly created rows

Tags: javascript, dynamic

so i have this function

```
function addRow(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
          case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;

        }

      }
    }
```

I also have this table template

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="m-t-10" name="chk" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_name[]" placeholder="Red,  Blue etc..">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_price[]" placeholder="Price">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_stock[]" placeholder="Stock">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div class="file">
                    <label class="file-label">
                        <input class="file-input" type="file" name="p_color_image[]" onchange="document.getElementById('color_image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
                        <span class="file-cta">
                            <span class="file-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="file-label">
                                Choose Multiple Files...
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="image" style="width:60px;">
                <img id="color_image" class="color_image" src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The function adds a new row like the above.

Now what i want is to **change the img element id to color_image1 or something** and also change the **onchange function getelementbyid to the id of the img element** so its able to target that element and preview the image that the user uploaded

The end result i am looking for is that i have a file upload for images and i target an img element with onchange function and preview the image before uploading.

Anyone got any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does that <div> already exist? Is there 1 or more? What are you trying to do? Insert that <div> into the new row?

Comment: @ash i updated my question, please take a look and tell me if its more clear what i want now! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about doing it.

First, you can store all the `color_image` imgs you have created into an array to give them a 'fake index'. And you can refer to the array length for subsequently created `color_image` imgs to give them the latest id. So every single color_image imgs would look like img `id ='color_image[id]'` where [id] is the index of the array.

Second, if you are only using img tag for your color_image, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName` to get the array of imgs.

Third, if you are using jQuery, you can use `$('.color_image:eq([id])')` to identify uniquely each `color_image` and put your tag to use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `color_image` ID just after you created the new row by searching the children of only the new row.

eg:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;


    //your existing loop ...
    .
    .

    var imageElement = row.querySelector("#color_image");
    // you can change the id now

    //do similar for the input/onchange

  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you ash!